# How can I id fetch arraylist from dictionary

Tags: java, jsp

I am working on a small project and i'm stuck at this line Currently my code is like

```
<% for (int j = 0; j < list1.Count; j++)
{
    foreach(Dictionary<string , string> itemLists in list1)
    {
    Response.Write( itemLists["image"] );
    }
} 
%>
```

and i cant do

```
foreach(Dictionary<string , string> itemLists in list[i])
{
Response.Write( itemList["image"] );
}
```

Comment: `foreach` does not exist in Java, neither the `for...in` loop... You seem to mix up Java (server-side) and JavaScript (client-side).

Comment: Is this really a Java? No way.

Comment: why you need to do that??

Comment: @sp00m `foreach` as a keyword doesn't exist in JavaScript, either.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is C# data structure (as well as attribute Count of List) - in Java, to achieve what you want, you would use some implementation of Map (f.e. HashMap) like that:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
}
```

It looks like you want, for some reason, use a list of maps, so try:

```
<% for (int j = 0; j < mapList.size(); j++) {
    for (final Map<String, String> map : mapList) {
        Response.Write(map.get("image"));
    }
} %>
```

Of course it involes preparing such structure in advance. Looking at type of mistake in your question I would strongly advise you to go and read manual for basic JSP (and probably some introduction to Java).